# Why do I get a stream of "permission denied" errors when using the find command on kali linux

Tags: linux, command, kali-linux

I am new to using Kali and I learned about the **find** command and wanted to try it out. I created a file called "Test" in my /home/kali/Documents Directory. Then I moved back to the [/] directory and used the command **find -name Test**

To my suprise, I recieved a plethora of errors and messages and I don't know what they mean or why they are popping up. Am I using the wrong command or using the wrong switches? In the examples I saw, the output was the directory of where the file was. What command and flags/switches do I use to find the exact location of the "Test" file i created in my Documents directory

[This is the command I wrote to the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clm31.png)

[This is the output I recieved (This is just a small piece of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6hOG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find command recursively search each file in each directory you provide:

```
find /home/kali /root -name test
```

This will search for a file or directory named `test` in the directories `/home/kali` and `/root`. By default, if you don't provide any directory, `find` will search in the current working directory named `.`. So in your case, these 3 commands are equivalent (because you are in the directory `/`):

```
find -name test
find . -name test
find / -name test
```

Now for your question. As I said, `find` will recursively look in every directory in each directory you provide (in your case the implied CWD `.` e.g. `/`).

This means that find will look for `test` in `/`, `/dev`, `/root`, `/proc`, ... and then in each subdirectory.

If you take `/root` for example, it belongs to the `root` user. If you look at the permissions on `/root`, you will find the following:

```
$ ls -l /
...
drwxr-x---  10 root root 4,0K 11 mai   20:17 root
...
```

As you can see, `/root` belongs to the `root` user and the `root` group as indicated by `root root` in the middle (the first refers to the owner and the second to the group). The letters at the left `drwxr-x---` show the permissions on this directory:

- `d` means that it's a directory
- `rwx` means that the owner (`root` in this case) has the right to read, write and execute this file.
- `r-x` means that the group `root` (users belonging to the group `root` i.e. only root in practice) can read and execute this file.
- `---` means that other users (i.e. `kali` for example) have no right on this file

Now what does it means to have the read, write and execute rights.
For a regular file, it's straight forward but for a directory it gets a bit tricky:

- read means that you can list the files/directories inside this directory
- write means that you can add file/directories in this directory
- execute means that you can `cd` into this directory or use this directory inside of a path

As other users (such as `kali`) have no rights on `/root`, `find` will fail with a permission denied error.

If you have the `sudo` rights on your machine, try:

```
sudo find / -name test
```

And this should work (although it will take some time to search your whole filesystem).